# html is different with headless chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

**Problem** 
When using Selenium with Chrome, the html is different when in headless mode.
**Details**
I have been trying to use Selenium to navigate to a website I want to scrape behind Google's login authentication. The problem is with the login page; the html is different when I use headless mode. Without headless mode, I can enter my username and password and login to the website no problem. It didn't work in headless mode, so when I retrieved the html, the html was different as follows:
Without headless
`<input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="メールアドレスを入力してください" name="identifier" value="" autocapitalize="none" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">`
With Headless
`<input id="Email" type="email" value="" spellcheck="false" name="Email" placeholder="メールアドレスを入力してください" autofocus="">`
(Don't mind the Japanese; it just says "Enter email")
I have tried changing the tags to send my credentials, but it just takes me to a site with a list of different languages.

**Solutions Tried**
On top of changing the tags, I tried adding `User Agent` with no luck. It gave me a different html that looks like the auto-generated Google page. I also added some options (see below) but that didn't help.
It would be great if there is a way I can use the same html as I would have using Chrome manually in headless mode. I know this is probably a Google thing, but is there a way? Thanks in advance.
**Some Code (Python)**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import chromedriver_binary
import requests
import time
username = "[REDACTED]"
username2 = "[REDACTED]"
password = "[REDACTED]"

url = "https://sites.google.com/[REDACTED]"

options = Options()
#options.binary_location = "[REDACTED]"
options.add_argument("--headless");
options.add_argument("--disable_gpu");
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080");
#options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/[REDACTED]", options=options)

driver.get(url)
print(driver.page_source)
n=0
while n < 5:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("identifierID").send_keys(username2)
        driver.find_element_by_id("next").click()
        print("good")
        break
    except:
        print("no")
        n += 1
print(driver.current_url)
# WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/challenge"))
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
...
```

(Please ignore the messy code, still debugging)

Comment: were you able to find a solution or a workaround? Or is running non-headlessly the only solution? I'm stuck with something similar

Comment: currently what i have is its running on firefox, which seems to work in headless mode. i ended up just leaving the browser logged into my google account so i can just go to the website w/o dealing with login (i have to login manually every two weeks or so).